# jQuery Checkbox is true if Textbox has value of 0 but false if the Textbox is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function where if the textbox has a value of 0 the checkbox will be set to true.
But I have this weird scenario where if the textbox is blank or greater than 0 I need the checkbox to be false

When I debug true this seems to be "" and 0 are the same thing
Does anyone know how I would go about making this work?

```
$(document).on('blur change keyup', '.CostInput', function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    $('input#Enquiry_Cost_InputFree_0').prop('checked', true);
  }

  if ($(this).val() > 0 || "") {
    $('input#Enquiry_Cost_InputFree_0').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

And I have created a JS fiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/Lqxuvr4w/9/

Comment: Well, there is a difference between `==` and `===` ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/523647/9741277

Comment: Have an exe on your expression: `$(this).val() > 0 || ""` you probably mean to say: `$(this).val() > 0 || $(this).val() === ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `==` and `===` in JavaScript.

```js
0 == ""  // => true
0 === "" // => false
```

You probably mean to say:

```js
$(document).on('blur change keyup', '.CostInput', function () {
  let val = $(this).val();

  if (+val === 0) {
    $('input#Enquiry_Cost_InputFree_0').prop('checked', true);
  }

  if (+val > 0 || val === "") {
    $('input#Enquiry_Cost_InputFree_0').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

For more information on how it works, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/9741277

Comment: Thanks for the update @leun4m but from your example in the text box if I enter the value 0 it doesn't populate the checkbox to true

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. Didn't test it. Since the textbox contains contains the value as `string` you need to convert it to a `number` type if you compare it with numeric values. Using `+val` should be safe -- even when `val` is not a number, because `NaN === 0` and `NaN > 0` will always return false.

Comment: Cheers thats much better than the solution I had which was adding "0" around the first if statement which worked but I guess it would have been buggy https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/Lqxuvr4w/11/